# Removing non alphanumeric character with some exceptions

Tags: php

I've came across this function that will do the first part I think

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $string);
```

But I don't want to remove '-','+' or '|'.
How can I make exceptions for these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 +|-]/", '', $string);
```

Comment: You dont need to escape `-` inside character class if used at 1st or last position.

Comment: @anubhava - Actually you do when it's between two characters. For that reason I put it at the end without escaping, but then I escaped it just in case he changed the order of things.

Comment: Correct that's what I mean by `if used at 1st or last position`

Comment: @anubhava - But you're right. It's really not necessary, so I'll remove it.

Comment: I'm using it for Query pre-prossesing and in some cases there could be a query such as 'beef-salmon'.

Comment: @You're in luck then. The expression will leave those hyphens in place.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the short form with `\w`

```
preg_replace("/[^\w\+\|\-\s]/", '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$string  = "abcdAbcd-0999345@dfsdf%+";
echo preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\-\| ]/", '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add with **\char**

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 \-\+\|]/", '', $string);
```

Demo: http://regexr.com?35lre